# Velocity.js - triggering animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I'm currently trying to get rid of a bunch of CSS animations and replace with the Velocity.js (along the way building in new animations).

At present I have a grid Item:

```
<div class="video-thumbnail">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x720" class="imgspacer" alt="{$info['title']}" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <a href="http://bbc.co.uk" class="thumbnail-link">
      <div class="title">
        <div class="title-display">
          <h5 class="SlideIn">Title One</h5>
          <h6 class="SlideIn">Title Two</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is controlled through CSS to fade in the `.overlay` element. What I then want to do is for the `h5` & `h6` classes to slide up in.

I've written the following code:

```
$('.overlay').hover(function(){ 
    $(this).find('.SlideIn').velocity("transition.slideUpIn", {stagger: 100, duration: 500});
});
```

But nothing seems to be happening. I'm quite new to Javascript so I'm presuming I've made a silly mistake somewhere along the line but can't work out what it is.

I've included a full snippet below and it can also be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jameshenry/ee290398/)

```js
$('.overlay').hover(function(){ 
 $(this).find('.SlideIn').velocity("transition.slideUpIn", {stagger: 100, duration: 500});
});
```

```css
#thumbnail-array {
 width: 100%;
}

.gutter-sizer {
 width: 0.03%;
}

.video-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #777;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: none;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 50;
}


.thumbnail-link {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /*important, forces to 100% height of parent*/
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none; 
}


.title {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: helvetica;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.title-display {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}

.video-thumbnail:hover .thumbnail-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity:1;
}

.imgspacer {
 width: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
}

.picturehelper {
 display: inline-block;
}

.video-thumbnail:hover .video {
    display: inline;
}

h5 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: normal;
}

h6 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-thumbnail">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x720" class="imgspacer" alt="{$info['title']}" />
  <div class="overlay">
    <a href="http://bbc.co.uk" class="thumbnail-link">
      <div class="title">
        <div class="title-display">
          <h5 class="SlideIn">Title One</h5>
          <h6 class="SlideIn">Title Two</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Off the bat I'd say you're missing a period in your `find` statement, should be `$(this).find('.SlideIn')`

Comment: Well spotted. Fixed that but still no joy with the script

Comment: Take a look at the error console. You should see that the velocity script isn't loading. Try locally hosting the velocity javascript files, those githubusercontent links aren't meant to be hotlinked to. I tried bringing the script inline in the code snippet by copying and pasting it directly into the script section, and it started working as expected.

Comment: Yep, you need to load jquery firsts, then velocity and then velocity.ui, if you added them in that orden on jsfidle your will work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @AldoRomo88 and @jmcgriz there was an issue with the load order of the scripts on the page.

I fixed the issue by simply loading query first up (and hosting the scripts on my own server!)